# Animate a game object in both animation and script

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have a side scrolling 2D game. The player (named `Default`) is a talking bird with all its limbs, One of the moving limbs is its eyeball (named `pupil`) and it has a script named `EyeController`.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is:

- case 1: Bird should **stare** at a target transform and follow it with eyes. (this is done in the code in `EyeController` script. you can find it at the end of my question)
- case 2: When I set a **trigger** in Bird's **animator** it starts the *eyeballing animation* and there is another **trigger** to go to default animation. (see the image below, two arrows coming out of `Any State`, so the triggers can change the animation anytime)

Problem is: **Case 1 only works if no animation is playing**. It stops following with eyes as soon as an animation starts.

While **Case 2 always works** and somehow prevents pupil to be changed from the code.

> **I want the code to override the animation.**

### Bird Animator structure:

[image]

Player has an animation with 3 layer.

1. Base Layer is additive and animates wings.
2. Mouth is override with weight 1 and animates talking (mouth and pupil and eyebrow).
3. Leg is override with weight 1 and has nothing in it

as you see below the pupil.position is animated in **Default Talking** and **Default Eyeballing**  states in `Mouth` layer.

**Not Talking** state (the default state in `Mouth` layer, its animation isn't shown here) has an empty animation.

[image]

### What I did:

I turned off `Write Defaults` on all animations. I know it resets animated values animator-wide.

When some triggers are set, the animation works and the pupil animates correctly; however when I change pupil.localPosition in script, it does NOT change the localPosition of the pupil.

part of `EyeController` script:

```
//sight controller calls this method in its FixedUpdate
public void LookAt(Vector3 direction)
{
    //transform.localPosition = direction;
    transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);//just to make sure direction isn't 0,0,0

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("change!");
}

//I tried Update() : same results
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //When I read localPosition it's always 0,0,0
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(transform.localPosition);
}
```

### output:

[image]

I've been struggling with this issue for weeks and cannot find a way to make it work both ways. If I delete pupil animations, I can animate it with code but I need the animation too as it is a complicated animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `LateUpdate()` ? If I remember correctly the execution order is something like `Update()` > `FixedUpdate()` > ***Animation*** > `LateUpdate()` > ***Rendering***.

Otherwise you could go for manually driven Animations using [`AnimationClip.SampleAnimation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SampleAnimation.html) but it would be quite heavy :)

Comment: Wow!!! I used LateUpdate method and I can't believe it's working perfectly! Thanks :-)